# Span's element content doesn't display entirely

Tags: html, css

Consider the following example from [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RAB9Y/9/).

```
<span>This is a very long text's line which containts in a span element. This is a very long text's line which containts in a span element. This is a very long text's line which containts in a span element. This is a very long text's line which contains in a span element. This is a very long text's line which contains in a span element. This is a very long text's line which containts in a span element. This is a very long text's line which contains in a span element. This is a very long text's line which contains in a span element. This is a very long text's line which contains in a span element. This is a very long text's line which contains in a span element. This is a very long text's line which contains in a span element.</span>
```

CSS styles:

```
span {
    background-color: aqua;
    padding:100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Why the text which contains in the `span` element is overlapping by the background and doesn't display entirely?

Comment: width cannot be applied to inline elements

Comment: @Pilot I know it. However, my question is about another thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Inline formatting contexts](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-formatting)

> Basically margin, padding and border can be set on inline-level
>   elements, but they may not behave as you expect. The behavior will
>   probably be OK if there's only one line, but other lines in the same
>   flow will likely exhibit behavior different from your expectations
>   (i.e. padding will not be respected). In addition, your inline box can
>   be broken if it contains breakable elements and reaches the margin of
>   the containing element; in that case, at the point of break, margins
>   and padding will not be respected as well.

I think you are looking for [word-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-spacing),

```
span {
    background-color: aqua;
    word-spacing:1px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

### For information:

**Inline elements and padding / margin**

While padding / margin can be applied to all sides of an inline element, only left and right padding margin will have an effect on surrounding content.

Answer (score 1):

You have too much padding and a short width even if you apply a display: block;

Comment: remove the width since it is not doing anything and change the padding

Comment: width attribute doesn't apply to n inline elements.

Comment: i'm assuming you need to control the width, so then you should add a display: block; to your rules. You can check a few changes on http://jsfiddle.net/RAB9Y/9/. But if that is not what you want, you should tell us how do you want it to look

Comment: No, I don't need to control a width. I'm just forget to delete width attribute after experimenting.

Comment: then there is no need to add a display: block;